# Plot a stable 4-periodic orbit

Tags: plotting, difference-equations

I have a question guys 
In Mathematica how I can plot a stable 4-periodic orbit in the logistic map with giving the four x values for the orbit and find the a value for which it goes through a period doubling and loose stability.

Comment: What have you tried? Please, invest a bit more effort into your question. What actually do you mean? General rule here is: No code, no answer. At least some equations are in order.

Comment: You could scan the problem from the textbook and post it here if unable to type it.